# Multiple references style

Tags: bibliographies

I am very new to LaTeX and this is my first article and i hope it won't be the last one. My problem is about references and how it appears in my article. Normally i put the author name as it appears on their journal and reports. So, sometimes they put First name Last name, or Last name then initials or initials then Last name and so on.

So, i end up with a mix of references styles. Some references start with initials and some not. Some start with Last name and some start with first name!

I want the same style for all of my references and i am studying engineering if there is a certain style for that.

I am using JabRef for my refernces and

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}
```

in the end of my document

For example:

I made the following bib entrys:

```
@Article{fault1,
Title = {Fault-tolerant control of the ship propulsion system benchmark},
Author= {Claudio Bonivento and Andrea Paoli and Lorenzo Marconi},
...}

@Conference{manoeuv,  
Title = {Simulation of the propulsion system behaviour during ship standard manoeuvres},    
Author= {G. Benvenuto and S. Brizzolara and M. Figari},
...}

@Conference{manoeuv1,
Title = {Simulation of Marine Diesel Engine Propulsion System Dynamics During Extreme Maneuvering}, 
Author = {George A. Livanos and George N. Simotas and George G. Dimopoulos and Nikolaos P. Kyrtatos},
...}
```

The result is 3 different styles !!!!!

I am not using biblatex or bibtex as well in my packages. I am using \usepackage{cite}

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us some (three or four) of your bib entrys, if possible two resulting with initials and two resulting with no initials? Which document class do you use, do you use package `biblatex` or only `bibtex`?  Please add some more informations to your question!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you use the multibib package http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib

Comment: I put the package in the beginning like this :
`\usepackage{multibib}`

and `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in the end and i still have different styles of references or author names as shown in the attached photo in my question

Comment: How does this answer address the concern expressed by the OP?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your setup correctly, you are using three different input conventions (full first names, full first names and middle initials, and initials of first names) for the authors' given names, and you are using a bibliography style (`unsrt`) that does not abbreviate first or middle names. Unsurprisingly, you therefore end up with three different output styles as well.

There are two, not mutually exclusive, paths toward getting a consistent output style:

- edit all entries in your bib file which currently have only initials of the authors' given names and expand them, as much as possible, to full first names and (if available) middle names (or at least their initials); and
- choose a bibliography style that abbreviates first names (and maybe even omits middle names entirely, even if the middle names or initials are stated in the bib file). You've "discovered" that `unsrt` doesn't abbreviate first names. However, there are lots and lots of bibliography styles out there that do.

Even if you decide to go with the second approach (i.e., using a style that truncates first names) for most of your papers, it's still useful to make the information in the bib file as complete as possible, including replacing initials with full first names. That way, if you ever submit a paper to a journal or conference volume that requires full first names, you won't have to scramble and research those names before being able to submit your paper.